# Change output voltage range from potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

I am using a 10K potentiometer to produce an adjustable voltage of 0..3.3 V from an input voltage of Vin = 3.3 V.

How can I change the circuit so my adjustable voltage range is 1..2 V ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: This is a very simple exercising of Ohm's Law and could have been found very easily on the Internet. (Some OPs reply that they've been searching the Internet hard and found nothing, which is ridiculous, obviously.)

Comment: is this a school question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy problem so you should work it out yourself for the educational value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7fKt2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The circuit.*

- You know what the voltages are at the top and bottom of the potentiometer, R2, because you have specified them.
- Since you have specified R2 you can therefore calculate the current through the pot.
- Knowing the current you can calculate the value of R3 that will give the minimum voltage.
- Similarly, knowing the current, you can calculate the value of R1 that will drop enough voltage to give you the required maximum output voltage.

---

Note: small 'k' for kilo. Capitals matter.

Comment: Thanks for process.

Comment: If it helped you solve the problem then please accept the answer to mark it solved.